# Google maps API using Vue wont display markers from database value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a database with the corresponding coordinates and the name for it. I am fetching by doing an axios request. I also have a static coordinate which will become the center for it. The problem is the markers for the coordinates from my api won show. I even log the coordinates and it shows me the correct one. What seems to be the problem of this?

My method

```
 data(){
            return{
                clinics:[],
                property:'',
            }
        },
 methods:{
            initMap(){
                //center
                this.property = {lat: 1.28237, lng: 103.783098};
                // const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (var i = 0; i < this.clinics.data.length; i++) {
                    var coords = this.clinics.data[i].coord;
                    console.log(coords['lat'])
                    console.log(coords['lng'])
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords['lat'],coords['lng']);
                    var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map
                    });
                }
                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 17, center: this.property})
                const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 200,    
                    fillColor: 'blue',
                    center:{lat: 1.28237, lng: 103.783098}
                }); 
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.property, map: map});
            },
        },
```

sample console output

```
app.js:1942 103.9056393
app.js:1941 1.307353803
app.js:1942 103.7845484
app.js:1941 1.334724904
```

axios sample response from my api

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "coord": {
        "lat": 1.307476844,
        "lng": 103.7601573
      },
      "clinic": "Chen Clinic"
    },
   ]
}
```

What i got (zoomed out to indicate that there are no markers)
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems its small mistake for me. Need to declare the static coordinate and the center first before placing the markers in order for it to work.

```
 initMap(){
                //center
                this.property = {lat: 1.28237, lng: 103.783098};
                // const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 17, center: this.property})
                const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 200,    
                    fillColor: 'blue',
                    center:{lat: 1.28237, lng: 103.783098}
                }); 
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: this.property, map: map});

                for (var i = 0; i < this.clinics.data.length; i++) {
                    var coords = this.clinics.data[i].coord;
                    console.log(coords['lat'])
                    console.log(coords['lng'])
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords['lat'],coords['lng']);
                    var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map
                    });
                }

            },
```

Comment: You needed to define the map before you use it.  Otherwise when you create the markers they don't have a valid map property.  You could create the markers first, then set their map property once you have a valid map (but that would be twice as much work).